# Preselect option in form with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select

I have a PHP application (Laravel 5.2)...I have a form that contains a select multiple, it's sent correctly to the controller, then in the controller I make some operations based on the information gived by the user in that form (is a search form exactly) and I send new information to the view and there I print again the form but I want to fill it with the data again.
I mean, now I want to pre-select the previously selected options, the user can send firstly:

["oldest","rating"]

I have that array in a PHP variable again in the view, but with PHP how can I preselect that ones. I'm looking for a elegant a clean way to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

**EDITED:**

This is my form:

```
<form action="myaction" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="File name">
</div>
<select name="orderBy[]"  multiple="multiple" class="form-control form-group" data-placeholder="Order by" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="oldest">Oldest</option>
    <option value="latest">Latest</option>
    <option value="rating">Rating</option>
    <option value="poster">Poster</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use Laravel Collective [`Form::select()`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists)

```
{!! Form::select('size', $dataArray, $selectedArray, ['multiple' => true]) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Collective will definitely make your life easier.

But in an effort to answer the question asked, what you would need to do is set the "selected" attribute for the options the user already has selected:

```
<option value="oldest"<?php echo in_array('oldest', $user_values_array) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Oldest</option>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if the options are hardcoded and not in a loop etc you could try:

say your variable/array sent to the view is:

```
 $myselection = ["oldest","rating"];
```

Then coudl try

```
<option @if(in_array('oldest', $myselection) selected @endif>oldest</option>
<option @if(in_array('latest', $myselection) selected @endif> latest </option>
```

based on blade, not tested so not too sure!